# In xfce4, how do I change to a left-handed mouse on the command line?

Tags: command-line, scripts, mouse, xfce

I change mouse hands often. It's easy to swap the buttons through xfce4-mouse-settings, but I'd like to script it or set it from the command line.

Something like:

```
 xfce4-mouse-settings --device=usb --buttons=left
```